# Fade container in and out css

Tags: html, css

I have code below for an accordion list I have created using pure CSS and HTML. When clicked on a heading my text flies in with a different background color. How would I make it so the container with the text and dif background color fades in and out when clicked to open and close? Like setting the opacity from 0 to 1? Anything helps, cheers.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Acordeon styles */

.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bold {
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #005bab;
  }

.top {
  margin-top:-20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:13px;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  color: #005bab;
  background: #e2ecf6;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .5s;
  -o-transition: max-height .5s;
  transition: max-height .5s;
  padding-left: 35px;
  background: #c3d7ea;
}

.tab-content .container {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  transform: scale(0.6);
  -webkit-transition: transform .5s;
  -o-transition: transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s;
  background: #f4f8fc;
}


/* :checked */

.input:checked~.tab-content {
  max-height: 25em;
}

.input:checked~.tab-content .container {
  transform: scale(1);
}

/* Icon */

.label::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

.input[type=checkbox]+.label::after {
  content: "+";
}

.input[type=radio]+.label::after {
  content: "";
}

.input[type=checkbox]:checked+.label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.input[type=radio]:checked+.label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.bottombar {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00688B;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-one" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="label" for="tab-one">Label One</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-two" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="label" for="tab-two">Label Two</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-three" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="label" for="tab-three">Label Three</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottombar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPYoxY

Comment: Sort of like this: https://codepen.io/chrisbuttery/pen/cxnmJ So when I click on the heading to open and close, the container fades in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you will need to `transition` multiple properties. It's quite easy. Use the same syntax you would use for a single property transition but do it for each property you want to transition and separate with commas `,`. For example:

```
.selector {
   color: white;
   opacity: 0;
   background-color: blue;
   transition: color 500ms ease-in-out, opacity 1000ms ease-in, background-color 500ms linear;
}
```

I updated your `transition` property in `.tab-content .container` along with setting `opacity`. Then defined `opacity` in .input:checked~.tab-content .container`.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Acordeon styles */

.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bold {
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #005bab;
  }

.top {
  margin-top:-20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:13px;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  color: #005bab;
  background: #e2ecf6;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .5s;
  -o-transition: max-height .5s;
  transition: max-height .5s;
  padding-left: 35px;
  background: #c3d7ea;
}

.tab-content .container {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.6);
  -webkit-transition: transform .5s, opacity .75s;
  -o-transition: transform .5s, opacity .75s;
  transition: transform .5s, opacity .75s;
  background: #f4f8fc;
}


/* :checked */

.input:checked~.tab-content {
  max-height: 25em;
}

.input:checked~.tab-content .container {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Icon */

.label::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

.input[type=checkbox]+.label::after {
  content: "+";
}

.input[type=radio]+.label::after {
  content: "";
}

.input[type=checkbox]:checked+.label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.input[type=radio]:checked+.label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.bottombar {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00688B;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-one" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="label" for="tab-one">Label One</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-two" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="label" for="tab-two">Label Two</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-three" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="label" for="tab-three">Label Three</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottombar"></div>
</div>
```